# Decision tree implementation in python that correctly handles categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, python, decision-trees

Is there a Decision tree implementation in python that correctly handles categorical covariates?

By "correct" I mean that it is able to send any subset of category levels down one daughter node and the rest down the the other. So far all implementations I came across required using one-hot-encoding representation. This is a serious limitation since it limits the tree to doing one-vs-rest splits which can greatly reduce accuracy.

To illustrate the problem we can take the iris dataset and randomly split each species to 2 sub-species:

```
data("iris")
library(rpart)
iris$Species <- factor(as.vector(unlist(tapply(iris$Species, iris$Species, 
           function(x) paste0(x, sample(rep(c(1,2), length.out = length(x))))))))
r_tree <- rpart(Sepal.Length~Species, data = iris)

r_tree
```

Which gives:

```
n= 150 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 102.1683 5.843333  
  2) Species=setosa1,setosa2 50   6.0882 5.006000 *
  3) Species=versicolor1,versicolor2,virginica1,virginica2 100  43.4956 6.262000  
    6) Species=versicolor1,versicolor2 50  13.0552 5.936000 *
    7) Species=virginica1,virginica2 50  19.8128 6.588000 *
```

We can see that the tree was able to split along the original species by sending both sub-species of each original species down the same node. If we were to use one-hot-encoding, at least one of the sub-species would have had to end up in a different node than its' counterpart.

More on why one-hot encoding reduces accuracy can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-hot-encoding-is-making-your-tree-based-ensembles-worse-heres-why-d64b282b5769).

Comment: For numeric,  Python sklearn implementation splits node in two. Split point is decided by finding gini at all possible split values. Split point corresponding to The highest gini  or lowest impurity is taken.

Comment: @amolgoel, this question only asks about categorical features.

Comment: I don't see why Iyar can't have both subspecies under same node. It will depend on if such a split is possible by gini maximization.

Comment: By definition every time a split is made one of the sub species will be sent down one node and the other down the other node.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any specific implementation in Python that handles categorical data as you are asking. `DecisionTreeClassifier` of sklearn does not handle categorical data as the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) says, and as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108832/passing-categorical-data-to-sklearn-decision-tree) discusses.

Historically, Quinlan's ID3 is the most well-known algorithm that handles **only** categorical variables, which has been later extended by the same author into C4.5 to handle **both** numerical and categorical variables; the latter holds also for CART developed by Breiman et. al.

If you are willing to try different frameworks and/or programming languages, you can explore the J48 implementation of [WEKA](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) in Java (Waikato Environment for Knowledge Analysis Machine Learning) or [DecisionTree.jl](https://github.com/JuliaAI/DecisionTree.jl) in Julia; in the latter case, I suggest you read this [issue](https://github.com/JuliaAI/DecisionTree.jl/issues/92) which is essentially your doubt. I hope that this gives you some hope in solving your problem as both codes are open-sourced and can be inspected, if necessary.